# metaprogramming passing value where type should be?

Tags: c++, templates

I have used an example from

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming

```
const unsigned long long y = Factorial<0>::value; // == 1
```

I understand the compiler can do a type check but I did not think you could put 0 where the type should be and it would be taken as the value.

Could someone explain how this is working ?

Thanks

Comment: By "explain how this is working", do you mean you want know how the compiler handles this?

Comment: exactly I do not know how the compiler is parsing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I did not think you could put 0 where the type should be and it would be taken as the value

The problem is the assumption: it is not "where the type should be". Rather, it is "where the template argument *may* be specified".

In this case, there is a *non-type template argument*.

It works, simply because it is a different feature than *type template arguments*.

It is just that way. I can recommend [C++ Templates: the Complete Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or many other books on [that list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read up on the basics of C++ templates.

- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1):

In that particular example:

```
template <int N>
struct Factorial {
    enum { value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};
```

The compiler generates the classes recursively. Remember, a template by itself is not a class, only a set of rules after which classes are generated.

Initially, only `Factorial<0>` exists. Then you write:

```
const int x = Factorial<4>::value;
```

which tells it it needs to generate the class `Factorial<4>` which would translate to:

```
template <>
struct Factorial<4> {
    enum { value = 4 * Factorial<3>::value };
};
```

which again tells it to generate the class `Factorial<3>` and so on. This stops when it reaches `Factorial<0>` because it was already defined and no new classes have to be generated to compute its `value` member.

Basically, it moves the computation from run-time to compile-time. Note that this doesn't always work (depending on the value of `N`, your compiler might not support that many levels of template recursion). Also, this increases code size.

This is for the how - why this works it's because it's permitted by the standard.